AWS amplify init provider use the role in the instance
I am trying to run aws amplify init with the cloudformation provider but seems like it only takes the aws access id and secret key method for its process. Any idea how I can configure the awscloudformationplugin to use the default session token in the instance from the role assigned?
This is the error I get.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessKeyId')


I tried assumeRole and expected the process not to look for any key configuration.
